# How to find the similar numeric column from one table with the column in another table

Tags: statistics, data-science

Currently i am working on a project in which the use case is for example:
there are two data frames one from the db and the other from the user uploaded file.The user uploaded file will be having unnamed columns

```
DB DATA FRAME
|customer_id | name | age | days_as_customer | revenue | payment |
|------------|------|-----|------------------|---------|---------|
| 00001      | x1   | 25  | 40               | 2000    |monthly  |
| 00002      | x2   | 51  | 200              | 10000   | yearly  |


USER UPLOADED FILE
|customer_id | C1   | C2  | C3               | C4      | c5        |
|------------|------|-----|------------------|---------|-----------|
| 00011      | x5   | 45  | 1                | 8000    |quarterly   |
| 00022      | x6   | 33  | 20               | 1000    |half-yearly|
```

What i need is that i have to match the columns from the user uploaded file to the db columns ie:

```
output 
{
age : C2,
days_as_customer : C3,
revenue : C4
}
```

Previously i tried using ks-test, qunatiles, skewness, central tendencies but the results are not as expected because most of time the uploaded file has central tendencies which is completely different from the db data frame

Can anyone suggest me any techniques to solve this ?

Comment: The "name" column can contain numbers and symbols, other columns can only contain numbers? If so, the name column is easy to find.

Comment: I got the solution for non-numeric columns. I need solution for the numeric columns